# How to save integer in MySQL timestamp column in Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, timestamp

I created a table  for my wordpress database within my plugin with:

```
global $wpdb;
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
global $charset_collate;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix .'tablename';
$sql="CREATE TABLE ".$table_name." (
   ...
   date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
   ...
) $charset_collate;
";
dbDelta($sql);
```

That works fine. But when I try to save integer values representing the date it saves "0000-00-00 00:00:00" except in one case it saves the correct date: "2014-01-11 01:59:00". But all integer values are valid timestamp dates (int(1401110159), int(1400525576), int(1400510041), ...). Here is the code I'm trying to insert my rows:

```
$wpdb->$table_name=$table_name;
$wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
   ...
   "date" => $my_date_integer_variable,
   ...
));
```

Anyone knows what's causing the error?

Comment: You need to convert the input dates to `Y-m:d H:i:s` format using `strtodate()` or `Datetime` object in PHP

Comment: Hi, it is an integer already. But I guess wordpress converts it to a string or something. But one value is saved as the correct date. It makes no sense to me. Really confusing :D

Comment: A `timestamp` column saves the value as integer **internally**, but  **displays** it back to you as `Y-m-d H:i:s`. That column is useful because it is always UTC - making it easy to offset it with time zone information. When you insert into a `timestamp` column, it wants a formatted value in the same way as it shows it back - meaning `Y-m-d H:i:s`. As the other guys have pointed out, you do it by formatting the date properly. If you want to insert the current time into a `timestamp`, you can issue `INSERT INTO your_ts_table SET ts_column = NOW();` (the last one is a MySQL function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL expects timestamps to be in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format when you do the insert not integer format.  ie. 2014-10-24 23:23:34

You can do conversion from int to date time format with:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1401110159)
```

In your case:

```
$wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
   ...
   "date" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $my_date_integer_variable)
   ...
));
```